# sentence creation function

Tags: java

I have the following function:

```
      public ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>> createSentences(ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>> gestures, int startIndex) {
            if (gestures.size() == 1) {

                return gestures;
            }


            ArrayList<Word> ret;
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>>();

            ArrayList<Word> tmp1 = gestures.get(0);
            gestures.remove(0);
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>> tmp2 = createSentences(gestures, startIndex + 1);


            for (Word s : tmp1) {
                for (Word s2 : tmp2.get(0)) {
                    ret = new ArrayList<Word>();
                    ret.add(s);
                    ret.add(s2);
                    result.add(ret);


                }


            }


 return result;
    }
```

Given an input:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>> test= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>>();

        ArrayList<Word> gest1 = new ArrayList<Word>();
        gest1.add(new Word("A", "N"));
        gest1.add(new Word("B", "V"));

         ArrayList<Word> gest2 = new ArrayList<Word>();
        gest2.add(new Word("C", "N"));
        gest2.add(new Word("D", "V"));



        test.add(gest1);
        test.add(gest2);
```

It produces following results:

```
[A, C]
[A, D]
[B, C]
[B, D]
```

which is fine but given an input:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>> test= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>>();

        ArrayList<Word> gest1 = new ArrayList<Word>();
        gest1.add(new Word("A", "N"));
        gest1.add(new Word("B", "V"));

         ArrayList<Word> gest2 = new ArrayList<Word>();
        gest2.add(new Word("C", "N"));
        gest2.add(new Word("D", "V"));

         ArrayList<Word> gest3 = new ArrayList<Word>();
        gest3.add(new Word("E", "N"));
        gest3.add(new Word("F", "V"));

        test.add(gest1);
        test.add(gest2);
        test.add(gest3);
```

It produces:

```
[A, C]
[A, E]
[B, C]
[B, E]
```

where I would like to achieve all possible combinations of matching like this:

```
[A, C, E]
[A, C, F]
[A, D, E]
[A, D, F]
[B, C, E]
[B, C, F]
[B, D, E]
[B, D, F]
```

Can somebody help me and rewrite the function to produce wanted results.

Comment: have you stepped through and tried debugging the code to see why this happens?

Comment: Yes. I have spent about 4 hours on this but getting all mixed up and don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest another loop in the two that already exist.

Or use a recursive algorithm which will work for any number of input word-lists.

**[EDIT]**

To make it more simple for you to understand what is going on, here are a couple of suggestions:

1. Create new types like `class WordList extends ArrayList<Word> {}` and `class Sentence extends ArrayList<Word> {}` That helps to make clear what you want. The code will be more readable.
2. Add helper methods to the new types. For example, add `List<Sentence> appendWords( WordList )` to `Sentence` to create new sentences from the original one where each has one word of the word list appended. That allows you to keep the code simple: Each method does exactly one thing.

That allows you to make the final algorithm pretty simple:

```
List<Sentence> result = new ArrayList<Sentence>();
result.add( new Sentence() ); // start with an empty sentence

for( WordList words : wordLists ) {
    List<Sentence> tmp = new ArrayList<Sentence>();

    for( Sentence s : result ) {
        tmp.addAll( s.appendWords( words ) );
    }

    result = tmp;
}
```

For each iteration of the main loop, all words of the next word list are appended to all previous results.

Comment: Yeah it has to work for any number of input word-lists. Can you give me an example how to use a recursive algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
for (Word s2 : tmp2.get(0)) {
```

means something like "for every **word** in the **first** sentence of tmp2". Why do you ignore the other sentences`tmp2.get(1)`, `tmp2.get(2)`, etc?

What you need is, "add every word from tmp1 to every **sentence** in tmp2", right?

```
for (Word word : tmp1) {
  for (List<Word> sentence : tmp2) {
    List<Word> tempSentence = new ArrayList<Word>();
    tempSentence.add(word);
    tempSentence.addAll(sentence);
    result.add(tempSentence);
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be
tempSentence.add(word);
instead of
tempSentence.add(tmp1);

as this one won't compile.

Comment: It still doesn't give the right results. It shoud match each word from position 1 with each word from position 2 and each word from position 3. Words from the same position can't be matched.